# Dynamic NSubprocess - start additional subprocess *after* NSuprocess is started

Tags: django-viewflow

We know that a subprocess should be started for `n` items when the task is activated, however, during the lifetime of the `NSubprocess` task, additional items could be found.

Let's say we have `Order` and `OrderItem`. When a customer submits an order and the flow gets to `fulfill_orderitems` (`NSubprocess` - `FulfillOrderItem` flow) task, we start the subprocess for each order item.

However, during the lifetime of this `fulfill_orderitems` task the customer can contact us to add additional item to the order. At this point we are forced to create a new `Order` process which is a bit tedioius; whereas if we could simply initiate a new `FulfillOrderItem` subprocess then things remain much simpler.

Obviously once the `fulfill_orderitems` is done and the customer calls afterwards to add additional item, then we'd have to either roll back (unpractical) or make a new `Order` process.

This is just a simple example, but generally speaking this behavior is quite useful. One could argue this *should* be a core functionality of `NSubprocess` (ie. to be able to add additional `n+1` subprocess during the liftetime of the task). How would one go about doing this?

We need to handle 2 things (from what I can see):

1. Function that starts this additional process. From what I understand it could be as simple as:

```py
    @Activation.status.transition(source=STATUS.STARTED)
    def start_subprocess(self, item):
        self.flow_task.subflow_task.run(self.task, item)
```

2. The view where the `item` is submitted through a form. Alternatively submit it through code directly. This bit I have trouble coming up with. It should be relatively simple, because it is very similar to what `StartSubprocess` does... (but we need to call the aforementioned `start_subprocess(item)`? However, I'm more interested in being able to call the method directly (eg through `DRF`).

Comment: This seems easily can be achieved by implementing custom node subclass.

Comment: @kmmbvnr Yes it should be simple, but there is so few examples available that I have trouble coming up with it (node & view). Perhaps add some more examples of custom nodes/gates/views to your docs and/or cookbook?